# Obtener porcentaje de avance medio de 3, 4 y 5 div's con jquery

Tags: jquery

Ante todo muchas gracias a todos los que leen esta pregunta y quieran ayudarme.
El titulo es confuso, pero aquí voy a tratar de plasmarlo:

Tengo un contenedor que a veces va a tener 3 div's, a veces 4 div's o a veces 5 div's, cada contenedor tiene una franja con css de un progreso, necesito obtener la mediana de los avances de todos los div's, si hay 3, o 4 o 5.

El código esta así:

```
<div id="contenedor" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="avance col-md-4 progreso1">
      <div class="progresso">
        <div style="width: 65%"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="avance col-md-4 progreso2">
      <div class="progresso">
        <div style="width: 20%"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="avance col-md-4 progreso3">
      <div class="progresso">
        <div style="width: 4%"></div>
      </div>
    </div>        
  </div>
</div>
```

Mi intensión es obtener una barra con el progreso total

en este caso seria algo así:

```
<div id="progreso-total" style="with: 29.66667%"></div>
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar con esto...

PD, entonces que hay que sumar todos los porcentajes (%) y dividirlos entre el numero de div's que hay con clase "avance".

Gracias.

Comment: Esto puede servir para detectar el numero de div's hijos que hay con la misma clase dentro del contendor general https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404544/jquery-count-number-of-divs-with-a-certain-class
http://api.jquery.com/length/

Comment: Cómo le cargas el progreso a cada `div`?Es decir, como les asignas el `width`? Porque obtener directamente el porcentaje no es simple. Ahora, si pudieras en cada `div` agregar algo como `data-progreso=""` y el porcentaje, sería todo más fácil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se define `progreso` como 0, luego se recorren cada uno de los divs `.avance` y se van sumando los porcentajes. La clave es usar [`.prop('style')`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37676393/1095101), porque si accedes directamente al width con `.css('width')` te devuelve el valor en `px`.

Si ésto necesitás hacerlo cada vez que alguno de los `.avance` cambia, habrá que meterlo dentro de una función.

```
var progreso = 0;

$('.avance').each(function () {
    progreso += parseFloat($('.progresso div', this).prop('style')['width']);
});

if (progreso) {
    progreso = (progreso / $('.avance').length) + '%';
}

$('#progreso-total').css('width', progreso);
```

Te dejo un [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t4h2f90e/) para que lo pruebes. Le agregué un `.text(progreso)` para que veas que porcentaje le está aplicando.

Comment: Muchas gracias... funciona bien. eres un ninja!